# 1 line of pixel missing with <dl> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm using a basic list in my website which works fine with FF and IE. However, there is one line of pixel missing  with Chrome.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3K8DB/19/) thanks to Jared in comments.

If you don't see the missing line, change the value of zoom, it will appear at some values (90% for instance on my PC).

Any idea of the source of the problem?

Screenshot:

[image]

The grey line jumps of one pixel.

Comment: You want us to look for *one* pixel? Where? At least tell us what colour it is..?

Comment: An entire line of pixels missing at the bottom.

Comment: An 'entire line of missing'? Hang on, your question title suggests that you have an *extra* pixel showing up; your comment suggests that you have pixels missing. Which is it?

Comment: Editing question and comment.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think he accidentally a word.

Comment: It looks identical to me in FF and Chrome...though I'm still not 100% sure what we are looking for.

Comment: It looks fine to me. How can you tell your missing  a line of pixels?

Comment: You have elements with identical `id` attributes.  No bueno.

Comment: BTW, ems are great for CSS but they do sometimes yield floating point values which are rounded differently by browsers. For example, the whole `dl` is "693.5833129882813px" wide in Chrome.

Comment: I can (barely, in your *image* but not my Chrome with the *live fiddle*) see what you're talking about (the height of the `dd` is one pixel *shorter* than the left). Why don't you set a specific *height* to the `dt` and `dd` elements? So there's not a discrepancy.

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm still not seeing the problem viewing the live fiddle in my Chrome (Windows 7, Chrome 20). I only discerned your problem when I blew up the image you originally posted in the question.

Comment: Go there: http://jsfiddle.net/3K8DB/19/ Then zoom 90%.

Comment: I may have answered the wrong question initially, but I believe this version of the demo fixes the problem (verified at 90% zoom in Chrome). Please let me know if you still see issues with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/pXrMH/

Comment: No your answer was perfect. The bug is fixed on the website too.

Comment: It took a while to be entirely clear on what the question was asking, but I added some additional notes to my answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*The main problems found:*

- On some screen sizes, the width of the `dt` and `dd`, plus the horizontal margins and padding, may be adding up to more than 100% for each line. The safest approach is to use % values for the widths, as well as the horizontal margins and padding, rather than `em`.
- The use of margins to place the `dd` tags on the same line as the `dt` tags is problematic. A safer way to implement the layout is to float every `dt` and `dd` tag and specify `clear:both` for each `dt` tag. It may be possible to do this correctly using margins, but floating the elements is much simpler.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/pXrMH/). *(note: This demo hasn't had any margins or padding added to it. The widths of the `dt` and `dd` should be reduced by however much is added to the horizontal margins or padding.)*

---

*Minor font problems found:*

**What's consistent**

- No `font-family` was specified, so the default serif font is used.
- No `font-size` was specified, so the default of 16px is used.
- `line-height:2em` is twice the font-size, which is twice 16px, which is 32px (shown by the height of the gray first line.
- The height of the gray first line is 32px in both Chrome and Firefox.

**What's not consistent**

- In Chrome, the default serif font with a `font-size` of 16px renders with a baseline height of 12px (the height of a capital H).
- In Firefox, the default serif font with a `font-size` of 16px renders with a baseline height of 11px.

**What can be avoided**

The default serif font renders inconsistently in different browsers. There's no way to prevent that font from doing so. But you can avoid some of the inconsistency by choosing a font other than the default serif font. Some fonts, like Arial, render more consistenly from browser-to-browser.

**What can't be avoided**

Even then however, there will still be some inconsistencies in how text renders. Within the line-height space used by the text, the position of the text will often vary by at least 1px from browser-to-browser. That's not something that can be prevented. It's a result of how the operating system happens to render that particular `font-family` at that particular `font-size` with that particular `line-height` in that particular browser. But the inconsistency can be minimized by always specifying an explicit `line-height`, which has already been done in this case.

**Summary**

Choosing a `font-family`, a `font-size`, and a `line-height` helps to minimize the inconsistency. But beyond that, there will always be little inconsistencies in the text that cannot be avoided. Every website on the internet has some amount of this. It's usually not very noticeable.

Comment: I think you're talking about comparing *across* browsers (which can be frustrating, Hail to the King, long live IE6). But I think... Maybe (could be wrong) it's in Chrome that the `dd` and the `dt` element's are different heights.

Comment: So, somehow (although I'm not seeing this without "help"), is what the OP is seeing in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/3K8DB/8/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Thanks for posting the modified demo. I'll take a look at this, and analyze it a bit more (hopefully I didn't entirely miss the point of the question :-)

Comment: You wouldn't have been the only one... Note, I added the `height: 32px/31px`. If you look *real* close at the itty-bitty image in the question, you'll see the slight indentation.

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer. I took Jared demo and clarified it: http://jsfiddle.net/3K8DB/16/

Comment: @ALS, I didn't actually do anything with that fiddle to "fix" anything, all I did was replicate your image's "missing one pixel height". Blown up and with contrasting color, this is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/lL11a.png

Comment: Oh i know. But on the fiddle I made it was really hard to see the problem. Yours is far clearer.